# "God mode" in Atlassian STASH

Tags: git, merge, pull-request, bitbucket-server

maybe who knows how I can merge pull request without approve. We use plugins "Approve Check Repository Hook" on Stash. For everybody need 2 approve, but for TeamLead needed some "God mode", when he can merge all pull request without approve. Thank you.

Comment: This kinda defeats the purpose of the plugin, no? :)

Comment: maybe;)
maybe have  a reason to editing this plugin?)

Comment: Can't the team lead commit straight to the destination branch?

Comment: Example. DEV1 made pull request, he must have 2 approve for merge, but Team Lead can merge pull request DEV1 without approve.

Answer (score 1):

I don;t think your Team Lead has "God mode". there are 2 ways in which he can do this

1. He has admin right so he turns off the option to "check for approvers" when he merges and turns it back on. Turning the check on and off is quick and does not send any notification , so there is no way you would know.
2. He has admin permissions on the target branch (which you don't) so he can just merge via git push instead of git pull

Comment: 1. I think about this, but it's not solution.
2. He has admin permissions on branch.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer on my question. I asked Java programmers to add this option to plugin "Approve Check Repository Hook" and they rewrite code for me. And now i can add "ignore users" who can merge without approve.

If somebody need this plugin, you can write me. Thx for all